# Redis SET Command Not Working on Any Database Except the Default

Tags: redis

I'm experiencing an issue were writes to any other DB except the default DB at index 0 aren't working. Below is a snapshot of using redis-cli to create a key in the default DB, which is successful. I then switch to DB 1 and run the same SET command, but then when trying to GET they key, it returns (nil), and when listing the key with the KEYS command, it returns (empty list or set). The same behavior occurs with any DB greater than 0.

This issue has only recently started occurring. I've been using DB 1 for quite a while with no issues. The server in the example below is the master of a set of three servers being managed with Sentinel.

```
redisprod01:6379> set testkey "test"
OK
redisprod01:6379> get testkey
"test"
redisprod01:6379> keys testkey
1) "testkey"
redisprod01:6379> select 1
OK
redisprod01:6379[1]> set testkey "test"
OK
redisprod01:6379[1]> get testkey
(nil)
redisprod01:6379[1]> keys testkey
(empty list or set)
```

Here's the output of the INFO command:

```
# Server
redis_version:2.8.4
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:a44a05d76f06a5d9
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.8.2
process_id:5172
run_id:c23834afdaf0e113f4cca368be9e88881fa82c91
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:7762453
uptime_in_days:89
hz:10
lru_clock:567194
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:1176
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:2000000696
used_memory_human:1.86G
used_memory_rss:2173636608
used_memory_peak:2003080696
used_memory_peak_human:1.87G
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.09
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.4.1

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:17067
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1536592844
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:5
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok

# Stats
total_connections_received:2617247
total_commands_processed:1810758972
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:1207
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:2
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:2
expired_keys:2190259
evicted_keys:128303561
keyspace_hits:456747821
keyspace_misses:421644916
pubsub_channels:2
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:54236

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:2
slave0:ip=10.93.109.123,port=6379,state=online,offset=2166765462577,lag=0
slave1:ip=10.93.109.122,port=6379,state=online,offset=2166765336151,lag=0
master_repl_offset:2166765934628
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:2166764886053
repl_backlog_histlen:1048576

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:59513.46
used_cpu_user:50583.63
used_cpu_sys_children:25643.75
used_cpu_user_children:184819.30

# Keyspace
db0:keys=238726,expires=220772,avg_ttl=83043319
```

Heres the config:

```
  1) "dbfilename"
  2) "dump.rdb"
  3) "requirepass"
  4) ""
  5) "masterauth"
  6) ""
  7) "unixsocket"
  8) ""
  9) "logfile"
 10) "/var/log/redis/redis.log"
 11) "pidfile"
 12) "/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid"
 13) "maxmemory"
 14) "2000000000"
 15) "maxmemory-samples"
 16) "3"
 17) "timeout"
 18) "0"
 19) "tcp-keepalive"
 20) "0"
 21) "auto-aof-rewrite-percentage"
 22) "100"
 23) "auto-aof-rewrite-min-size"
 24) "67108864"
 25) "hash-max-ziplist-entries"
 26) "512"
 27) "hash-max-ziplist-value"
 28) "64"
 29) "list-max-ziplist-entries"
 30) "512"
 31) "list-max-ziplist-value"
 32) "64"
 33) "set-max-intset-entries"
 34) "512"
 35) "zset-max-ziplist-entries"
 36) "128"
 37) "zset-max-ziplist-value"
 38) "64"
 39) "lua-time-limit"
 40) "5000"
 41) "slowlog-log-slower-than"
 42) "10000"
 43) "slowlog-max-len"
 44) "1024"
 45) "port"
 46) "6379"
 47) "databases"
 48) "16"
 49) "repl-ping-slave-period"
 50) "10"
 51) "repl-timeout"
 52) "60"
 53) "repl-backlog-size"
 54) "1048576"
 55) "repl-backlog-ttl"
 56) "3600"
 57) "maxclients"
 58) "10000"
 59) "watchdog-period"
 60) "0"
 61) "slave-priority"
 62) "100"
 63) "min-slaves-to-write"
 64) "0"
 65) "min-slaves-max-lag"
 66) "10"
 67) "hz"
 68) "10"
 69) "no-appendfsync-on-rewrite"
 70) "no"
 71) "slave-serve-stale-data"
 72) "yes"
 73) "slave-read-only"
 74) "yes"
 75) "stop-writes-on-bgsave-error"
 76) "yes"
 77) "daemonize"
 78) "yes"
 79) "rdbcompression"
 80) "yes"
 81) "rdbchecksum"
 82) "yes"
 83) "activerehashing"
 84) "yes"
 85) "repl-disable-tcp-nodelay"
 86) "no"
 87) "aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync"
 88) "yes"
 89) "appendonly"
 90) "no"
 91) "dir"
 92) "/var/lib/redis"
 93) "maxmemory-policy"
 94) "allkeys-lru"
 95) "appendfsync"
 96) "everysec"
 97) "save"
 98) "900 1 300 10 60 10000"
 99) "loglevel"
100) "notice"
101) "client-output-buffer-limit"
102) "normal 0 0 0 slave 268435456 67108864 60 pubsub 33554432 8388608 60"
103) "unixsocketperm"
104) "0"
105) "slaveof"
106) ""
107) "notify-keyspace-events"
108) ""
109) "bind"
110) "10.93.109.121"
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but running locally

Answer (score 0):

**select** command is not supported for redis cluster. Did you recently transition from standalone redis to clustered redis ? Reference: https://redis.io/commands/select

Comment: No, no recent changes in the architecture. The server is the master in a set of servers managed by Sentinel -- is that considered a Redis cluster?

Answer (score 0):

This is running locally, but rather than using `redis-cli SELECT 1`, I ran `redis-cli -n 1`. Once I did that I was able set keys and retrieve them successfully on that database.

Switching between multiple databases that way seems to have done the trick for me.

Bear in mind that is running on my local machine.